# Printing list of inbox emails to include date and time received

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-excel-2013

In Outlook 2013, how can I print a list of my inbox showing date and time

Comment: What have you tried? Showing date and time of what? Have you tried Print Screen? Or File > Print > Table Style?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very unclear, but I will hazard a guess that you want to print a list of the emails in your inbox rather than a single email message.

You do this by being in your Inbox or the folder you wish to print the emails in, then going to **File** > **Print** and selecting **Table Style**.